# Write a program in C that repeatedly reads doubles from stdin until there are no more to read and then prints out the number of items the average

Tags: c, while-loop, double, scanf

I am having trouble printing out the number of items entered and the average of this program and I am supposed to use a while loop can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double n;
    int counter = 0;
    double sum = 0.0, average;
    scanf("%lf", &n);
    while (1 != scanf("%lf", &n)) {
        counter++;
        scanf("%lf", &n);
        sum = sum + n;
        printf("%d", counter);
        average = sum / counter;
        printf("%lf", average);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what it's supposed to look like

Input: `2.2 2.4 1.5 1.1 3.3 5.5 Q`
Output: `6 2.666667`

Comment: so how does it look now?

Comment: Why are there so many `scanf` calls? You do realise that each `scanf` will consume one of the inputs? And since you don't use the result of every `scanf` some of the inputs will be discarded.

Comment: `while(1 != scanf("%lf", &n))` will cause the loop to stop as soon as an input is matched. Is that really what you want? I guess you meant to do `==` rather than `!=`.

Comment: And the `printf` calls probably need to be outside the loop. That is, the results should be shown at the end. Same for the `average` calculation - it only needs to be done once outside the loop and not for every input.

Comment: Oh okay I see now I only put one scanf and it is showing progress and I will put the print calls outside the loop to see if it works some more

Answer (score 1):

You should read the values in a loop, testing if `scanf()` returns `1` for successful conversion, update the `sum` and `counter` inside the body of the `while` loop and output the average and count after the end of the loop.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int counter = 0;
    double n, sum = 0.0;
    while (scanf("%lf", &n) == 1) {
        counter++;
        sum = sum + n;
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        printf("no values\n");
    } else {
        printf("%d %f\n", counter, sum / counter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: might consider checking counter to avoid division by zero, but otherwise a short and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is too much redundancy in your code:

```
double n;
int counter = 0;
double sum = 0.0, average;
// you do not need the following initial read
// (see reconstructed while condition)
scanf("%lf", &n);

// replace the following line with "while (1)"
while (1 != scanf("%lf", &n)) {
    // sth like the following if block is to be inserted to check end of input
    if (scanf("%lf", &n) == 0) {
        break;
    }

    counter++; // ok
    // you do not need the following line
    // if block takes care of the input
    scanf("%lf", &n);

    sum = sum + n; // ok
    
    // better pull the remaining lines out of the while loop
    printf("%d\n", counter); // better to insert '\n' here
    average = sum / counter;
    printf("%lf\n", average);  // and here '\n'
}

return 0;
```

And btw, for the code above, your input layout had to be :

```
2.2
2.4
1.5
1.1
3.3
5.5
Q
```

A working example might be, like;

```
int main(void) {
    double n;
    int counter = 0;
    double sum = 0.0, average;

    while (1) {
        if (scanf("%lf", &n) == 0) {
            break;
        }

        counter++;
        sum = sum + n;
    }

    printf("%d\n", counter);
    average = sum / counter;
    printf("%lf\n", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing. The code shown keeps some parts that are incorrect (with comments) and then adds some code that partially helps. It would be better to present a fully working solution rather than a mix of incorrect and corrected code.

Comment: I thought, it would be better for her/him to reconstruct the code on his own, than writing the working code; but I will.

Comment: That could be good too. In that case, don't add/change bits of the original code. Keep the original code exactly as OP has it and then add comments to that code pointing out the problems. It's the mix that's confusing.

Comment: `if (scanf("%lf", &n) == 0)` will fail to detect the end of file if no conversion failure happens before `EOF`. Use `while (scanf("%lf", &n) == 1)`